# Admin now missing from Authors dropdown

Tags: wordpress

I've been running my Wordpress install for months with 2 users, the original administrator which I use and another admin account created for my co-admin. We've been posting fine, no issues, all was great.

Two days ago I created another user, and now whenever I log in as the original admin (my account) I am no longer in the authors dropdown list. Any new users I create show up, but my original account is no longer listed.

I can't figure out what's going on, nor how to restore myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure, how this could happen, but maybe you could add a filter to `'wp_dropdown_users'` and reinject yourself. :)

See **wp-includes/user.php** `function wp_dropdown_users()` for details. Anyway, I’d ask in the WordPress forums and file a bug for this case.